# Unbound local error: ("local variable referenced before assignment")

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-2.x

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

d = [{'Cabin': 'F G13'},{'Cabin': 'A32 A45'},{'Cabin': 'F23 F36'},{'Cabin': 'B24'},{'Cabin': nan}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def deck_list(row):
    if row['Cabin']!=row['Cabin']:
        cabinid = 'NONE'
    else:
        cabinsubstr = row['Cabin'].split(' ')
        for i in cabinsubstr:
            if i.find('F ') != -1:
                cabinid = i[0][0]
                break
            if i.find('F ') == 0:
                cabinid = i[1][0]
                break       
    return cabinid

df['Deck_ID'] = df.apply(deck_list, axis=1)
```

Am I missing something? I've written something akin to this plenty of times and I've never gotten this error but maybe it's something really stupid?

Comment: If it helps, I'm simply trying to make a column 'Deck_ID' that will do the following logic:

if row['Cabin'] == nan, 'NONE'
if row['Cabin'] == 'F G14', 'G'
if row['Cabin'] == 'A34 A32', 'A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to write this, using [vectorized string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods) is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Cabin': 'F G13'},
                   {'Cabin': 'A32 A45'},
                   {'Cabin': 'F23 F36'},
                   {'Cabin': 'B24'},
                   {'Cabin': nan}])

cabin_parts = df['Cabin'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
conditions = [pd.isnull(df['Cabin']), 
              df['Cabin'].str.startswith('F').astype(bool), 
              ~df['Cabin'].str.contains('F').astype(bool)]
choices = [None, 
           cabin_parts[1].str[0], 
           cabin_parts[0].str[0]]

df['Deck_ID'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

which yields

```
     Cabin Deck_ID
0    F G13       G
1  A32 A45       A
2  F23 F36       F
3      B24       B
4      NaN    None
```

---

Alternatively, if I understand the `Cabin` --> `Deck_ID` naming pattern correctly, perhaps

```
df['Deck_ID'] = df['Cabin'].str.extract(r'(\D\d*)?\s*(\D\d+)', expand=True)[1].str[0]
```

would suffice, since

```
In [86]: df['Cabin'].str.extract(r'(\D\d*)?\s*(\D\d+)', expand=True)
Out[86]: 
     0    1
0    F  G13
1  A32  A45
2  F23  F36
3  NaN  B24
4  NaN  NaN
```

The regex pattern `(\D\d*)?\s*(\D\d+)` has the following meaning:

```
(\D\d*)?     first capturing group: 0-or-1 (nondigit followed by 0-or-more digits)
\s*          0-or-more whitespace
(\D\d+)      second capturing group: (nondigit followed by 1-or-more digits)
```

Comment: damn. That's good!

On something small like this, it may not matter but in your experience unutbu, is this more efficient for large data sets since it avoids for loops?

Comment: @Analysa: Yes, that's exactly why the vectorized string methods are preferred. Applying a Cythonized function (like the string methods) to whole columns is generally far faster than looping over rows when the DataFrame is large.

Answer (score 0):

OHH I just ran my logic. I think it is indeed something stupid.

```
cabinsubstr = ['C23', 'C25', 'C27']
for i in cabinsubstr:
    i.find('F ') != -1
```

isn't even reading true because I should have if it DOES ==-1 since it didn't find it. I'm an idiot ;)